# XSLT: How to find value of the node by another node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not sure I am asking the question correctly, that's why I cannot find an answer anywhere. But basically I need to match a node with another node and use a sibling node as a value instead. Here is an example

```
<group>
    <section>
      <reference>123</reference>
      <name>ABC</name>
    </section>
    <section>
      <reference>456</reference>
      <name>DEF</name>
   </section>
</group>
<element>
   <reference>123</reference>
   <price>20.00</price>
</element>
```

And in my XSL template I want to display Price and Name, so I need to match Reference from the Element to Reference in Section and display Name.

> ABC - 20.00

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to match Reference from the Element to Reference in Section and
>   display Name.

XSLT has a special feature called **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** just for this purpose. For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="section" match="section" use="reference" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="element">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('section', reference)/name"/>
                <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="price"/>      
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following **well-formed** input:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <group>
    <section>
      <reference>123</reference>
      <name>ABC</name>
    </section>
    <section>
      <reference>456</reference>
      <name>DEF</name>
    </section>
  </group>
  <element>
    <reference>123</reference>
    <price>20.00</price>
  </element>
</root>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <item>ABC - 20.00</item>
</output>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="sss" match="section" use="reference"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="element">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('sss', reference)/name"/>
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use two similar predicates on your XPath expressions. In this example a root node called `<root>` is assumed to wrap the rest of your XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:value-of select="group/section[reference/text() = ../../element/reference/text()]/name" /> - <xsl:value-of select="element[reference/text() = ../group/section/reference/text()]/price" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
ABC - 20.00
```

Comment: You are assuming there will be only one `element` with a matching `section`. I see no reason for such assumption; in fact I believe it's reasonable to expect there will be many.