# Concatenation of * in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a input like the below:

I have a requirement where i need to concatenate all the values in the below input with the * sign and get the corresponding

Input XML:

---

```
<Root>
    <DBCallOutput>
        <ATTRIBUTE6>IN10</ATTRIBUTE6>
    </DBCallOutput>
    <DBCallOutput>
        <ATTRIBUTE6>IN11</ATTRIBUTE6>
    </DBCallOutput>
    <DBCallOutput>
        <ATTRIBUTE6>IN12</ATTRIBUTE6>
    </DBCallOutput>
    <DBCallOutput>
        <ATTRIBUTE6>IN13</ATTRIBUTE6>
    </DBCallOutput>
    <DBCallOutput>
        <ATTRIBUTE6>IN14</ATTRIBUTE6>
    </DBCallOutput>
    <DBCallOutput>
        <ATTRIBUTE6>IN17</ATTRIBUTE6>
    </DBCallOutput>
    <DBCallOutput>
        <ATTRIBUTE6>IN20</ATTRIBUTE6>
    </DBCallOutput>
    <DBCallOutput>
        <ATTRIBUTE6>IN21</ATTRIBUTE6>
    </DBCallOutput>
</Root>
```

The expected output is

```
<result> IN10* IN11* IN12* IN13* IN14* IN17* IN20* IN21</result>
```

Can anyone help on this

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, not both.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, this is trivial:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="DBCallOutput/ATTRIBUTE6" separator="* "/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

---

To achieve the same in XSLT 1.0, use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="DBCallOutput">
```

and output the value of `ATTRIBUTE6`, followed by:

```
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">* </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="2.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="Root">
            <result>
                <xsl:for-each select="DBCallOutput">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE6"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() !=last()">
                        <xsl:text>* </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>    
            </result>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This generates your desired output as you want.

Comment: Why do you repeat an answer already given? Both here and in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42850220/3016153

Comment: hi @michael.hor257k I am trying the other question today but unable to find the solution. Can you please help on the Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138468/in-xslt-i-have-a-requirement-like-adding-all-mspfee-amount-under-invoice-elemen