# In XSLT, I have a requirement like adding all MSPFEE amount under invoice element

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a requirement like below:

In XSLT, I have a requirement like adding all MSPFEE amount under Invoice element based on FieldglassInvoiceId element, means if FieldglassInvoiceId is same then i need to consider only one the first MSP .

Input:

```
<Invoices xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/Invoices_FTP">
         <Invoice>
            <ConsolidatedInvoiceID>ONE</ConsolidatedInvoiceID>
            <FieldglassInvoiceID>123</FieldglassInvoiceID>
            <GrossInvoiceAmount>1600.00</GrossInvoiceAmount>
            <NetInvoiceAmount>1600.00</NetInvoiceAmount>
            <InvoiceAdjustmentAmount>0.00</InvoiceAdjustmentAmount>
            <MSPFee>40.00</MSPFee>
            <MSPFeeAdjustmentAmount>0.00</MSPFeeAdjustmentAmount>
         </Invoice>
         <Invoice>
            <ConsolidatedInvoiceID>ONE</ConsolidatedInvoiceID>
            <FieldglassInvoiceID>123</FieldglassInvoiceID>
            <GrossInvoiceAmount>1600.00</GrossInvoiceAmount>
            <NetInvoiceAmount>1600.00</NetInvoiceAmount>
            <InvoiceAdjustmentAmount>0.00</InvoiceAdjustmentAmount>
            <MSPFee>40.00</MSPFee>
            <MSPFeeAdjustmentAmount>0.00</MSPFeeAdjustmentAmount>
         </Invoice>
         <Invoice>
            <ConsolidatedInvoiceID>ONE</ConsolidatedInvoiceID>
            <FieldglassInvoiceID>456</FieldglassInvoiceID>
            <GrossInvoiceAmount>1600.00</GrossInvoiceAmount>
            <NetInvoiceAmount>1600.00</NetInvoiceAmount>
            <InvoiceAdjustmentAmount>0.00</InvoiceAdjustmentAmount>
            <MSPFee>40.00</MSPFee>
            <MSPFeeAdjustmentAmount>0.00</MSPFeeAdjustmentAmount>
         </Invoice>
        <Invoice>
            <ConsolidatedInvoiceID>ONE</ConsolidatedInvoiceID>
            <FieldglassInvoiceID>789</FieldglassInvoiceID>
            <GrossInvoiceAmount>1600.00</GrossInvoiceAmount>
            <NetInvoiceAmount>1600.00</NetInvoiceAmount>
            <InvoiceAdjustmentAmount>0.00</InvoiceAdjustmentAmount>
            <MSPFee>40.00</MSPFee>
            <MSPFeeAdjustmentAmount>0.00</MSPFeeAdjustmentAmount>
         </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

Required Output:

```
<Invoices xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/Invoices_FTP">
         <Invoice>
                <Amount>180</Amount> -- Addition of all first MSPFEE element from all FieldGlassInvoiceId under one ConsolidatedInvoiceID
         </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

Comment: sorry Output should be:

Comment: That kind of logic is possible in XSL-T, but I don't recommend it.  XSL-T is for transformations, not complex business logic.

Comment: <Invoices xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/Invoices_FTP">
         <Invoice>
                <Amount>120</Amount> 
         </Invoice>
</Invoices>

Comment: Can some please update on this?

Comment: SO doesn't work that way.  You aren't guaranteed to get an answer.

Comment: Where does the number 180 in your expected output come from? I can't relate it to anything in your input? (My guess from your description of the problem was that you were trying to group Invoices by the value of FieldglassInvoiceID, but your example output doesn't give support to that guess.)

Comment: @ Michael, Thanks for the reply.Actullay my mistake, the output should be 120

Comment: @ Michale, Actually My Mistake, the output should be "120", I am trying to do Group-by with "ConsolidatedInvoiceID" and then I need to add all "MS Fee" which has unique "FieldglassInvoiceID". Hope this is clear.

Comment: Any Update on this? or is it not possible to achieve this using XSLT?

Comment: @VishnuPrakash you're acting as if SO is some kind of paid service. What did you do research the in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure I understand your question. You're looking for the sum of each `<Invoice>`'s `<MSPFee>` value, but only for those `<Invoice>`'s that have the first instance of a unique `<FieldglassInvoiceID>` value.

This should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://TargetNamespace.com/Invoices_FTP"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://TargetNamespace.com/Invoices_FTP"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Invoices>
            <Amount>
                <xsl:variable name="amounts" as="xs:double *">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="Invoices/Invoice" group-by="xs:double(FieldglassInvoiceID)">
                        <xsl:sequence select="xs:double(MSPFee)"/>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($amounts)"/>
            </Amount>
        </Invoices>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```